nmtui usb0 interface help
I am trying to connect my Samsung S9 to a Variscite imx8m DART-PLUS module using USB-Tethering.  I would then like to mirror or control the DART-PLUS module from the phone.
I am using Debian 12.
I was able to successfully accomplish this with an S9 phone and a Raspberry Pi 4 using the instructions on the following site: https://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/
The instructions say to create a new usb0 interface by adding the following information to the /etc/network/interfaces file:
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.42.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.42.0
broadcast 192.168.42.255
After adding this information, and rebooting, I was able to see the interface using ifconfig (note: I had to connect the phone with a USB cable and enable USB-Tethering first).
I have been unable to add a usb0 interface to my Variscite DART-PLUS module.  I tried using the /etc/network/interfaces file, but I have been told that this file no longer gets used.
I have tried using nmtui to setup a usb0 interface, and although I do not receive any error messages which using nmtui, a usb0 interface never shows up in ifconfig.
PLEASE HELP!!!
